# How to check if Current Record is Parent of Nth Level Child (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, parent-child

In PostgreSQL database, looking for solution to check if given 2 records have Parent and Nth Child Relation.

Have a following table layout,

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(...)
  private Long idNumber;

  private String empName;

  private Long managerId;  
}
```

Suppose we have table data in following format,

```
+----------+---------+-----------+
| idNumber | empName | managerId |
+----------+---------+-----------+
|        1 | Emp1    | NULL      |
|        2 | Emp2    | 1 (Emp1)  |
|        3 | Emp3    | 1 (Emp1)  |
|        4 | Emp4    | 2 (Emp2)  |
|        5 | Emp5    | 4 (Emp4)  |
+----------+---------+-----------+
```

If we get input Id's for "Emp1" and "Emp5", using single SQL query is it possible to determine if "Emp1" is super parent of "Emp5".

One option i found was to retrieve all Nth Level records using "WITH RECURSIVE" option.

http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-recursive-view/

This would required loading all intermediate data.

Wanted to check if there is as better way to check if relationship exists between 2 N level records. Only looking for direct relation using boolean flag. Don't need to display any of the intermediate rows.

Thanks

Comment: You have to do some kind of edge-walk, since there's no direct relationship between the parent and leaf entries.

Comment: Thanks Craig for the quick response. Any sample code will be very helpful. I am good with Java, but still bit novice with advanced SQL. I will try my best to continue from any sample code that is provided.

Comment: A recursive CTE is how I'd do it. Then I'd wrap it in an outer query to filter out the unwanted rows. I don't have time to try to write it right now, and I'm not great with recursive CTEs, but hopefully someone will be able to pop along.